# Concatenate Cells While Removing Duplicates (Remove first comma)

Tags: excel, vba

So I was able to find how to concatenate a row/column of cells while removing duplicates.

But although the equation while it concatenates a list there is a comma to start it off, it just looks unclean.

", a, b, c, d, e" instead of just "a, b, c, d, e"

```
Public Function MakeList(myRange As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    Dim c As Range

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each c In myRange
            If Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False Then .Item(c.Value) = c.Value
        Next c
        MakeList = Join(.keys, " ,")
    End With
End Function
```

I'm hoping to be able to get rid of that first comma if it is possible. Thank you.

Comment: **MakeList = Mid(Join(.keys, " ,"),3)**

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem.  Perhaps you have a non-hidden cell which is blank?

Comment: This could potentially return wrong results if a sheet different from the one containing `myRange` is active

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be getting a leading delimiter unless you are starting with a blank cell.

```
Public Function MakeList(myRange As Range)
    Application.Volatile
    Dim c As Range

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each c In myRange
            If not c.parent.Rows(c.Row).Hidden and trim(c.value) <> "" Then .Item(c.Value) = c.Value
        Next c
        MakeList = Join(.keys, " ,")
    End With
End Function
```

Optionally, you could remove the leading delimiter before returning the concatenated string.

```
Public Function MakeList(myRange As Range, _
                         optional d as string = " ,")
    Application.Volatile
    Dim c As Range

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each c In myRange
            If c.parent.Rows(c.Row).Hidden = False Then .Item(c.Value) = c.Value
        Next c
        MakeList = Join(.keys, d)
        if left(makelist, len(d) = d then makelist = mid(makelist, len(d)+1)
    End With
End Function
```